# Problem with setting edges labels in a graph of nodes with given position coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have an 11x11 dataframe called "loc" containing node's position coordinates (X, Y and Z) with node names as index.
I have another dataframe "dist" containing distance between nodes while node names on both column headers and index. 
I want to plot the network graph such that each node is labelled with its name (index of loc). Also each node should be connected to every other node.

However I want that each edge is labelled with the distance between the two nodes. I

I have created the graph, plotted the node with labels and draw edges between them. However could not draw labels to legends.

```
#####  Example data similar to my actual data
coord     = np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=(11,3))  
lab       = ['AP', 'STA1', 'STA2', 'STA3', 'STA4', 'STA5', 'STA6', 'STA7', 
'STA8', 'STA9', 'STA10']
loc       = pd.DataFrame.from_records(coord, columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'], 
index=lab)
d         = distance_matrix(loc,loc) # Distance between each device
dist      = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d, columns=lab)
dist      = dist.set_index(dist.columns)
dist      = dist.round(decimals=1)

##########  Network Plot without edges
coord         = np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=(11,3))  
lab           = ['AP', 'STA1', 'STA2', 'STA3', 'STA4', 'STA5', 'STA6', 
'STA7', 'STA8', 'STA9', 'STA10']
loc           = pd.DataFrame.from_records(coord, columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'], 
index=lab)


d         = distance_matrix(loc,loc) # Distance between each device
dist      = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d, columns=lab)
dist      = dist.set_index(dist.columns)
dist      = dist.round(decimals=1)

# Add the nodes to graph
G=nx.Graph() 
for i in range(len(loc)):
    G.add_node(loc.index[i])

pos = loc.ix[:,0:2].transpose().to_dict(orient='list')

# Add edges
for i in range(len(loc)):
    for j in range(len(loc)):
        G.add_edge(loc.index[i], loc.index[j])

# Draw the network
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
ax.axis('equal')
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, arrows= True, with_labels=True, node_size=600, 
node_shape='o', alpha=0.5, font_size=10) 
plt.show()
```

1) The given code produce the required graph but without edges labels. I want to draw labels in the center of the edge or somewhere to be more readable. Remember, the edge_label represent the distance between the two nodes (i.e. the value in the "dist" dataframe for which the index and column header has same value).
2) Can we draw the same network in 3D as the nodes have three corrdinates (X,Y and Z). As in my code I draw only the X and Y cooridnates.

Answer (score 0):

For drawing edges' labels you will need to first add this data to the edges:

```
G.add_edge(loc.index[i], loc.index[j], weight=d[i][j])
```

Then for drawing the labels you can call `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels()`

And all together:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#####  Example data similar to my actual data
coord     = np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=(11,3))
lab       = ['AP', 'STA1', 'STA2', 'STA3', 'STA4', 'STA5', 'STA6', 'STA7',
'STA8', 'STA9', 'STA10']
loc       = pd.DataFrame.from_records(coord, columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
index=lab)
d         = scipy.spatial.distance_matrix(loc,loc) # Distance between each device
dist      = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d, columns=lab)
dist      = dist.set_index(dist.columns)
dist      = dist.round(decimals=1)

##########  Network Plot without edges
coord         = np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=(11,3))
lab           = ['AP', 'STA1', 'STA2', 'STA3', 'STA4', 'STA5', 'STA6',
'STA7', 'STA8', 'STA9', 'STA10']
loc           = pd.DataFrame.from_records(coord, columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
index=lab)


d         = scipy.spatial.distance_matrix(loc,loc) # Distance between each device
dist      = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d, columns=lab)
dist      = dist.set_index(dist.columns)
dist      = dist.round(decimals=1)

# Add the nodes to graph
G=nx.Graph()
for i in range(len(loc)):
    G.add_node(loc.index[i])

pos = loc.ix[:,0:2].transpose().to_dict(orient='list')

# Add edges
for i in range(len(loc)):
    for j in range(len(loc)):
        G.add_edge(loc.index[i], loc.index[j], weight='%.2f' % d[i][j])

# Draw the network
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
ax.axis('equal')
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, arrows= True, with_labels=True, node_size=600, node_shape='o', alpha=0.5, font_size=10)
edge_labels = {(u, v): d['weight'] for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True)}
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels, font_size=8, rotate=False)
plt.show()
```

For 3D plotting you can use *mplot3d*, [here](http://www.idtools.com.au/3d-network-graphs-python-mplot3d-toolkit/)'s an example.